# How can i do DRY for many similar joins in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-5, dry

I have an interface with ten fields and i often join two Queryables of this interface. Most of the time all of the ten fields have to be equal but sometimes not. Right now i solve this by having a lot of static extensionmethods but they all look kinda the same and with every variant i add i fear i will add an error (Wrong fields etc...).

```
public static class MyJoins
{
public static IQueryable<T> JoinOnAll<T, TA, TB>(this IQueryable<TA> query, IQueryable<TB> otherQuery)
    where TA : IMyInterface where TB : IMyInterface where T : class, IJoinInterface<TA, TB>, new()
{
    return query.Join(otherQuery,
        a => new { a.F1, a.F2, a.F3, a.F4, a.F5, a.F6, a.F7, a.F8, a.F9, a.F10 },
        b => new { b.F1, b.F2, b.F3, b.F4, b.F5, b.F6, b.F7, b.F8, b.F9, b.F10 },
        (t, p) => new T { AA = a, BB = b });
}

public static IQueryable<T> JoinOnAllButF2<T, TA, TB>(this IQueryable<TA> query, IQueryable<TB> otherQuery)
    where TA : IMyInterface where TB : IMyInterface where T : class, IJoinInterface<TA, TB>, new()
{
    return query.Join(otherQuery,
        a => new { a.F1,       a.F3, a.F4, a.F5, a.F6, a.F7, a.F8, a.F9, a.F10 },
        b => new { b.F1,       b.F3, b.F4, b.F5, b.F6, b.F7, b.F8, b.F9, b.F10 },
        (t, p) => new T { AA = a, BB = b });
}

public static IQueryable<T> JoinOnAllButF4F7<T, TA, TB>(this IQueryable<TA> query, IQueryable<TB> otherQuery)
    where TA : IMyInterface where TB : IMyInterface where T : class, IJoinInterface<TA, TB>, new()
{
    return query.Join(otherQuery,
        a => new { a.F1, a.F2, a.F3,       a.F5, a.F6,       a.F8, a.F9, a.F10 },
        b => new { b.F1, b.F2, b.F3,       b.F5, b.F6,       b.F8, b.F9, b.F10 },
        (t, p) => new T { AA = a, BB = b });
}
//and many more of this
}
```

I there a way to pass the fields to compare on as a parameter? (I think there is not)
Are there other ways to solve this mass of nearly duplicated code?

----How i would use this-------------------------

I mainly use it in a way where i split querys, join them and then concat them:

```
IQueryable a = ......
IQueryable b = ......
var firstPart = a.Where(MyExpression).JoinOnAll(b);
var secondPart = a.Where(OtherExpression).JoinOnAllButF2(b);
var thirdPart = a.Where(AnotherExpression).JoinOnAllButF1F2F8(b);
var joinResult = firstPart.Concat(secondpart).Concat(thirdPart);
var joinResultFiltered = joinResult.WHere(AndAnotherExpression);
return joinResultFiltered;
```

I have many functions like this but the Expressions and joins are always different.

Additional Info because someone in the Commetns asked:

The interfaces are basically just this

```
public interface IMyInterface{
    public string F1 {get;set;}
    public string F2 {get;set;}
    // up to F10
}
```

Comment: "I there a way to pass the fields to compare on as a parameter? (I think there is not)" - do you consider generating the expressions by reflection a viable solution, or have you ruled out that path?

Comment: Show several usage samples. I'm working with `IQueryable` a lot and never had problem with DRY and joins.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper no i havent ruled that out but i dont have any experience with that

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv well i dont know what to say. I showed you three examples. I have many more of this methods and each on of them is used several times. Honestly its just the messy child of different companies having similar product descriptions but never the same.

Comment: It is not examples it is implementation. Show how do you use that in real code and why. Do you use EF?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv added a usecase and yes i use efcore but i  am interested in a solution that works only for linq too.

Comment: Let me check my snippets. I've already did such implementation. Otherwise will recreate new one.

Comment: Add your interfaces to the question. I can create "universal" join. Anyway I have feeling that you are designed things wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```cs
public static class MyJoins
{
    private sealed class ReplacementVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ReplacementVisitor(LambdaExpression source, Expression toFind, Expression replaceWith)
        {
            SourceParameters = source.Parameters;
            ToFind = toFind;
            ReplaceWith = replaceWith;
        }
        
        private IReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression> SourceParameters { get; }
        private Expression ToFind { get; }
        private Expression ReplaceWith { get; }
        
        private Expression ReplaceNode(Expression node) => node == ToFind ? ReplaceWith : node;

        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node) => ReplaceNode(node);

        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            var result = ReplaceNode(node);
            if (result == node) result = base.VisitBinary(node);
            return result;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (SourceParameters.Contains(node)) return ReplaceNode(node);
            return SourceParameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == node.Name) ?? node;
        }
        
    }
    
    private static Expression<Func<T, object>> BuildJoinFields<T>(LambdaExpression fn) where T : IMyInterface
    {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var visitor = new ReplacementVisitor(fn, fn.Parameters[0], p);
        var body = visitor.Visit(fn.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, p);
    }
    
    public static IQueryable<T> JoinOn<T, TA, TB>(
        this IQueryable<TA> query, 
        IQueryable<TB> otherQuery, 
        Expression<Func<IMyInterface, object>> fieldsToJoinOn)
        where TA : IMyInterface
        where TB : IMyInterface,
        where T : class, IJoinInterface<TA, TB>, new()
    {
        Expression<Func<TA, object>> aFields = BuildJoinFields<TA>(fieldsToJoinOn);
        Expression<Func<TB, object>> bFields = BuildJoinFields<TB>(fieldsToJoinOn);
        return query.Join(otherQuery, aFields, bFields, (a, b) => new T { AA = a, BB = b });
    }
}
```

```cs
query.JoinOn(otherQuery, x => new { x.F1, x.F2, x.F3, ... })
```

Although I'm not convinced the compiler will be able to infer the type for type parameter `T`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. It does not care about interfaces, join key is based on outer type. And if property not found inner type, it will throw exception.

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public interface IJoinInterface<TA, TB>
    {
        public TA AA { get; set; }
        public TB BB { get; set; }
    }
    class JoinHandler<TA, TB> : IJoinInterface<TA, TB>
    {
        public TA AA { get; set; }
        public TB BB { get; set; }
    }

    public static IQueryable<IJoinInterface<TA, TB>> JoinOn<TA, TB, TKey>(
        this IQueryable<TA> outer, 
        IQueryable<TB> inner, 
        Expression<Func<TA, TKey>> joinKey)
    {
        var innerParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TB), "inner");
        var innerKey   = BuildKey(joinKey, innerParam);

        Expression<Func<TA, TB, IJoinInterface<TA, TB>>> resultExpression = (a, b) => new JoinHandler<TA, TB> {AA = a, BB = b};

        var queryExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Join),
            new[] { typeof(TA), typeof(TB), typeof(TKey), typeof(IJoinInterface<TA, TB>) }, outer.Expression, inner.Expression,
            joinKey, innerKey, resultExpression);

        return outer.Provider.CreateQuery<IJoinInterface<TA, TB>>(queryExpression);
    }

    private static LambdaExpression BuildKey(LambdaExpression source, ParameterExpression param)
    {
        var body = new MemberReplacer(source.Parameters[0], param).Visit(source.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda(body, param);
    }

    class MemberReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public MemberReplacer(ParameterExpression sourceParam, ParameterExpression destParam)
        {
            SourceParam = sourceParam;
            DestParam   = destParam;
        }

        public ParameterExpression SourceParam { get; }
        public ParameterExpression DestParam { get; }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Expression == SourceParam)
            {
                if (DestParam.Type == SourceParam.Type)
                    return node.Update(DestParam);

                var destProp = DestParam.Type.GetProperty(node.Member.Name);
                if (destProp == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Type '{DestParam.Type.Name}' has no property '{node.Member.Name}'.");

                return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(DestParam, destProp);
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Solution is closer to previous answer, but more universal and do not care about specific interfaces realizations.